# Plain RSA with $3$ primes, find all integers $x$ so that $x$ is equal to $y$ when $y= e_K(x) = x^{b} \bmod n$

Tags: rsa, multi-prime-rsa

I'm using the notation from the book: Cryptography: Theory and Practice, Third Edition.

I have a cryptosystem with the following information:

$n = p_1 p_2 p_3$ and integer $x$ is encrypted using $y = e_K(x) =  x^b$ $mod$ $n$ and the decryption is $x = d_K(y) =  y^a \bmod n$
when $ab\equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$

$n=231$, so: $p_1 = 11$, $p_2 = 7$, $p_3 = 3$

I want to find all $x$ so $x= e_K(x) =  x^b \bmod{231}$

I tried this:

$x^b-x \equiv 0 \pmod{231}$

$x(x^{b-1}-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{231}$

$x = 0$, $x = 1$ are solutions, to find the rest:

$\varphi(231)=120$ so $ab\equiv 1\pmod{120}$ but I don't know how to continue.

Since $120=2^{3}\cdot3\cdot5$ so $2\nmid{b}$ and $3\nmid{b}$ and $5\nmid{b}$

by following the RSA page from wikipedia: [key generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation):

$\lambda (231)=30$, so $1 \lt b \lt 30 $, the only integers that left from $1, 2, \ldots, 30$ are primes. then using Fermat's little theorem implies that for any integer $a$: $$a^{p} \equiv a\pmod p$$ so,

I tried to check CRT, CRT implies that $e_K(x) = x$ iff $x^b \equiv x \pmod{p_i}$ for $i=1,2,3$.

But I still don't know how to continue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the integers $x$ such that, for all $b$, $x^b \equiv x \pmod n$.

You almost have it!  You've correctly identified $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ as solutions.  If you *had* a solution $x$, what can you say about $x_i := x \bmod p_i$ for each $p_i$—how are $x_i$ and ${x_i}^b$ related modulo $p_i$?  Can you use the solutions $x = 0$ or $x = 1$ modulo $n$ as inspirations to find solutions modulo $p_i$ and recombine them into solutions modulo $n$?

Comment: How do I use solutions $x=0$ or $x=1$ for that?
Using CRT, $x^b\ \equiv x \pmod{11}$  and $x^b\ \equiv x \pmod{7}$ and $x^b\ \equiv x \pmod{3}$, treating it like system of congruences and $N_1 = 231/3 = 77$, $N_2 = 231/7 = 33$, $N_3 = 231/11 = 21$ so a solution of the system of congruences is $$x^b = \sum_{i=1}^3 x\cdot M_i \cdot N_i$$ and $M_1 = 2$, $M_2 = 3$, $M_3 = 10$
so, $x^b = (x \cdot 2\cdot 77 + x \cdot 3\cdot 33 + x \cdot 10\cdot 21) = 463 \cdot x$. I don't understand how to continue.

Comment: @Asaf Can you _separately_ find ${x_i}^b \equiv x_i \pmod{p_i}$, and then combine them?

Comment: By using the fact that $0 \le x \lt 231$ and $1 \lt b \lt 30$ to check all the possible $x$ that ${x_i}^b \equiv x_i \pmod{p_i}$?
I don't understand.

Comment: @Asaf If ${x_i}^b \equiv x_i \pmod{p_i}$ for prime $p_i$, what can you say about $x_i \bmod p_i$?

Comment: that $0 \le x_i \lt p_i$, because $p_3 = 3$ so I have to check only $x=2$?

Comment: @Asaf So, if $x_i = 0$ or $x_i = 1$, then ${x_i}^b \equiv x_i \pmod{p_i}$.  Are there any other _integers_ $x_i$ such that ${x_i}^b \equiv x_i \pmod{p_i}$?  (Not restricted to $0 \leq x_i < p_i$!)

Comment: I don't know. The only thing that comes in mind is Fermat's little theorem but this restricted to $0 \leq x_i < p_i $

Comment: @Asaf How about $x_i = p_i$, or $x_i = p_i + 1$?  (Fermat's little theorem is a red herring.  Focus on another fact you observed already about $x^b = x$.)

Comment: if $x_i = p_i$ than ${x_i}^b \equiv 0 \pmod{p_i}$.
but for  $x_i = p_{i} + 1$ I don't know.

Comment: Hint: $u \mapsto u \bmod p_i$ is a ring homomorphism, so $(u \bmod p_i)^b = u^b \bmod p_i$.

Comment: But this statement: $(u \bmod p_i)^b = u^b \bmod p_i$ is true only when $(u \bmod p_i)^b \bmod p_i= u^b \bmod p_i$.
How can I calculate the integers $x$ using that?

Comment: @Asaf Try to find ${x_i}^b \bmod p_i$ when $x_i = p_i + 1$, using this ring homomorphism.  (You're right, I should have written that as a congruence or clearly identified whether talking about integers or cosets, but the point is that $u \mapsto u \bmod p_i$ is a ring homomorphism and therefore commutes with ring operations like $u \mapsto u^b$ whether in $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/p_i\mathbb Z$.)